# tar command for another directory

Tags: tar

I have a tarball (x.tar) in home/sermet directory. When I'm in different directory on terminal like, /opt#, I want to untar the x.tar in its current directory (home/sermet). How can I perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you be

> tar -xf /home/sermet/x.tar -C /home/sermet/

That will extract x.tar in your home.

Answer (score 3):

```
tar xvf /home/sermet/x.tar /home/sermet/
```

Mind you this will mess up your /home/sermet/ if the tar has not got subdirectories in it.